# Can't set dmColor and dmPrintQuality for CutePDF Custom PDF Writer with programmatic access

Tags: windows, winapi, printing

We are using CutePDF Custom PDF Writer with programmatic access to automatically generate PDFs in a C Windows-application.

We use `DocumentProperties()` to set the paper size and orientation, but we are not able to change the print in color and print quality settings.

Changes that works:

```
// Set landscape or portrait
pi2->pDevMode->dmFields = DM_ORIENTATION;
pi2->pDevMode->dmOrientation = dmOrientation;

// Custom paper size
pi2->pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_PAPERLENGTH | DM_PAPERWIDTH | DM_PAPERSIZE;
pi2->pDevMode->dmPaperWidth = PDFPrinterSizes[papper].dmPaperWidth;
pi2->pDevMode->dmPaperLength = PDFPrinterSizes[papper].dmPaperLength;
pi2->pDevMode->dmPaperSize = DMPAPER_USER;
```

Changes that have no effect:

```
// Print in 600 dpi
pi2->pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_PRINTQUALITY;
pi2->pDevMode->dmPrintQuality = 600;

// Print in color
pi2->pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_COLOR;
pi2->pDevMode->dmColor = DMCOLOR_COLOR;
```

Instead the document is printed with the last used settings in the system. I.e. if I print in color to a different printer the PDF:s will be in color. If I print to another print in monochrome I will get a Monochrome output.

Is the `dmColor` setting intended to always be `DMCOLOR_COLOR` to support grey scale output?
How to I force the CutePDF Custom PDF Writer to print in color?

Bonus question: Is the problem with `dmPrintQuality` related?

Comment: If PDF file is vector format it will most likely ignore print quality. If source is color then you might be able to downgrade to `DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME` but not the otherway.

Comment: The vectors in the PDF will look very different at 72dpi and 300 dpi. It may be another setting than dmPrintQuality, but the driver has a setting for the resolution of the vector coordinates.

As for the color / grey scale, the same data sent to the PDF printer will generate different results depending on the setting for the last print on the system (even if it is to another printer). Can there be driver specific settings for color?

Comment: Try `dmPrintQuality = DMRES_HIGH` maybe CutePDF will recognize it.

Comment: I did. DMRES_HIGH sets dmPrintQuality to 4000 dpi, but I don't see any effect on the output. :-(